# What is the pushforward of differential forms?

Tags: differential-forms, riemann-surfaces

Suppose that $f: X \to Y$ is a degree $n$ map of Riemann surfaces. If we are given a holomorphic differential $1$-form $\omega$ on $X$, how do we define the pushforward $f_*\omega$? I can't seem to find the definition written down anywhere so any references / insight would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You can push forward the corresponding cohomology class (this is called the "transfer"). You can also, sort of, push forward a 1-form if your map is a regular ramified covering (by averaging).

Comment: @MoisheKohan Interesting, could you elaborate on the "averaging" process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a construction of push-forward (of sorts), assuming that $f: X\to Y$ is an $n$-fold regular ramified covering, i.e. there exists a group $G$ (of order $n$) of biholomorphic automorphisms of $X$ such that $f(p)=f(q)\iff Gp=Gq$.

1. Replace the holomorphic 1-form $\omega$ by its $G$-average:
   $$
   \alpha= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{g\in G} g^*\omega. 
   $$
   Now, $\alpha$ (unlike $\omega$) is $G$-invariant.
2. Define a 1-form $\beta$ on $Y$ as follows: If $y\in Y$ is not a ramification point of $f$, $v\in T_yY$, then pick $x\in f^{-1}(y)$. There exists $u\in T_xX$ such that $df(u)=v$. Set
   $$
   \beta(u):=\alpha(v).  
   $$
   If $y$ is a ramification (aka critical) point of $f$, then $\beta(y)=0\in T^*_yY$.

It is a nice exercise to check that this construction does yield a 1-form $\beta$ on $Y$ (one needs to verify smoothness and independence of the choice of $x$; the latter is ensured by the $G$-invariance of $\alpha$). Also, if $\alpha\in \Lambda^{1,0}(X)$, then so is $\beta$, if $\alpha$ is holomorphic, so is $\beta$, etc.

Then one can regard $\beta$ as a push-forward of $\alpha$.

Comment: What will be the de Rham differential $d_{dR} f_{*}\alpha$ of the pushforward form?

Comment: @RobertHanson: Do you know how to compute $d \phi_* \alpha$, if $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism?

Comment: Ah I see, for a global diffeomorphism $\phi_{*} = (\phi^{-1})^{*}$ and chain rule gives $d\phi_{*}\alpha = \phi_{*}d\alpha$. Now working with the covering map $f$ in local charts such that $f$ is a diffeomorphism, we also get $df_{*}\alpha = f_{*}d\alpha$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

Pushforward of differential forms is a standard operation, described in many expository texts.

A fairly detailed presentation is given in Chapter VII of

- Werner Greub, Stephen Halperin, Ray Vanstone.  Connections, Curvature, and Cohomology.  Volume I.  [De Rham Cohomology of Manifolds and Vector Bundles](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0079-8169(08)62844-5).  Pure and Applied Mathematics 47A (1972), Academic Press.

Of course, for a covering map (like in your case) the pushforward map can be defined much more easily: given an arbitrary $y∈Y$, pick a sufficiently small neighborhood $U$ of $y$ so that the preimage of $U$ under $f$ is a projection from the product of $U$ with a discrete set $S$.  The projection map identifies each of the leaves indexed by $S$ with $U$ via a diffeomorphism (in our case, a biholomorphic map), so we can transport $ω$ along these diffeomorphisms and sum over all $s∈S$.  Since $f$ has degree $n$, the cardinality of $S$ equals $n$ and the sum is finite.  The result is clearly independent of the choice of $U$.  For a local diffeomorphism, we can instead cover $X$ by a locally finite cover $V$ such that every $V_j$ maps injectively into $Y$, then take similar sums as described above (no longer with a fixed choice of $U$).

This construction works for any finite degree holomorphic map, and there is no need to require the covering to be regular.  If the map is ramified, first remove the ramification points, which are isolated in $Y$.

Comment: What you described works for finite-to-one covering maps but does not work if  is merely a finite-to-one local diffeomorphism.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Sure, I meant a covering map, of course.  But for local diffeomorphisms a simple modification fixes the problem, I adjusted the wording accordingly.

Comment: Alas, what you wrote for local diffeomorphisms is so imprecise, it is not even a definition. Try to work out the details in an example, such as $f(t)=e^{it}, t\in (0,4\pi), \omega=dt$, $Y=S^1$ and check if your $f_*(\omega)$ is even continuous.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: The pushforward along local diffeomorphisms (as opposed to coverings) is not continuous and I never said it is.  For an easier example, take an open embedding of manifolds and pushforward a nonvanishing form; the result is not continuous.  The definition is perfectly precise.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice sheaf theory way of looking at this using the Trace map (Stacks Project: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0FK6), which exists under the conditions you prescribe to $f$ (in fact these assumptions can be weakened). The Trace map is a chain map on the de Rham complexes
$$
Tr : f_{*}\Omega^{\bullet}_X \to \Omega_Y^{\bullet}.
$$
View a differential form $\alpha \in \Omega^p(X)$ as a morphism $\alpha : \mathcal{O}_X \to \Omega^p_X$. A-priori the pushforward is a morphism of sheaves
$$
f_{*} \alpha : f_{*}\mathcal{O}_X \to f_{*}\Omega^p_X.
$$
Now composing with $f^{\sharp}: \mathcal{O}_Y \to f_{*}\mathcal{O}_X$ and $Tr$ gives you a morphism
$$
\mathcal{O}_Y \to f_{*}\mathcal{O}_X \to f_{*} \Omega_X^{p} \to \Omega^{p}_Y,
$$
Which defines a p-form $\beta = f_{*}\alpha \in \Omega^{p}(Y)$.

If sheaves are your thing then it is satisfying to connect this point of view with the previous answers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).